# pst-abspos and afterpage not producing the effect I want: is there an aftereverypage?

Tags: eso-pic, afterpage, everyshi, pst-abspos

I'm trying to create a document which looks like it's been printed on a ruled page.  I know I can probably do this in `tikZ`, but I would like to be able to do this in `pstricks`.

The option `absolute` for the package `pst-abspos` only works correctly when the first command on a given page is `\pstSetAbsoluteOrigin`.   If LaTeX is making the page breaks for me then I need a way to automatically call this.

To remedy this, I thought I could use `afterpage` to issue the `\pstSetAbosluteOrigin` at the beginning of each page.  However, `afterpage` only seems to take effect on the second page of my document.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[absolute]{pst-abspos}
\psset{unit=1cm}%
\newcommand{\myrules}{%
    \pstSetAbsoluteOrigin%
    \pstPutAbs[](0.0,0.0){%
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(0,0)
        \multido{\rx=-2.5+-0.50}{50}{\psline[linecolor=blue!20](0,\rx)(\paperwidth,\rx)}%
        \psline[linecolor=red](2.5,0)(2.5,-\paperheight)
    \end{pspicture}}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\afterpage{\myrules}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-114]

\end{document}
```

I can duplicate this unexpected behavior of `\afterpage` with or without `pst-abspos` such as with `\afterpage{Hello World}`.  But, I was worried that I'd get solutions that would work with something so minimal but not cooperate with the `pst-abspos` tricks I'm trying.

**EDIT**

After reading the documentation for `afterpage` for the umpteenth time now, I see that it only take effect after the current page.  So, I guess what I want is something more like `aftereverypage`.

I know there's an `everypage` package, but when I use `\AddEverypageHook{\myrule}`, the formatting of the rules is completely wrong.

When I use the `everyshi` package, I'm getting extra space at the top of everypage (or so it seems to me).

Here's a slightly more complicated MWE which illustrates this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[absolute]{pst-abspos}
\psset{unit=1cm}%
\newcommand{\myrules}{%
    \pstSetAbsoluteOrigin%
    \pstPutAbs(0.0,0.0){%
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(0,0)%
        \multido{\dx=-2.5+-\baselineskip}{58}{\psline[linecolor=blue!20](0,\dx)(\paperwidth,\dx)}%
        \psline[linecolor=red](2.5,0)(2.5,-\paperheight)%
    \end{pspicture}}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{everyshi}
\EveryShipout{\myrules}
\begin{document}\myrules%
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Notice how on page one the spacing at the top of the page is correct, but not on the subsequent pages.  The space between the rules is much smaller than I actually want.  But, I chose this spacing for this last MWE to help show the unwanted space appearing at the top of the pages after page one.

Comment: Have you tried `background` package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that looks like a problem with package `everyshi`. Here is a solution with `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[notitlepage,relative]{pst-abspos}
\newcommand{\myrules}{%
  \pstSetRelativeOrigin(0,0)%
    \pstPutAbs(0,0){%
        \multido{\dx=-2.5+-\baselineskip}{58}{\psline[linecolor=blue!20,unit=1cm](0,\dx)(\paperwidth,\dx)}%
        \psline[linecolor=red,unit=1cm](2.5,0)(2.5,-\paperheight)}}%
%--------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[texcoord]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{showframe}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\myrules}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

[image]